# String decleration length in C

Tags: c, char, scanf

So I'm writing a small program (I'm new to C, coming from C++), and I want to take in a string of maximum length ten.

I declare a character array as

```
#define SYMBOL_MAX_LEN 10 //Maximum length a symbol can be from the user (NOT including null character)
.
.
.
char symbol[SYMBOL_MAX_LEN + 1]; //Holds the symbol given by the user (+1 for null character)
```

So why is it when I use:

```
scanf("%s", symbol); //Take in a symbol given by the user as a string
```

I am able to type '01234567890', and the program will still store the entire value?

My questions are:

1. Does scanf not prevent values from being recorded in the adjacent
   blocks of memory after `symbol`?
2. How could I prevent the user from entering a value of greater than length `SYMBOL_MAX_LEN`?
3. Does scanf put the null terminating character into `symbol` automatically, or is that something I will need to do manually?

Comment: Usually the compiler padds the size of the array to be a multiple of four to keep data alignment, so the real size is not 11 but 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `scanf` not prevent values from being recorded in the adjacent blocks of memory after symbol?

As far as I know, No.

> How could I prevent the user from entering a value of greater than length SYMBOL_MAX_LEN?

By using buffer safe functions like `fgets`.

> Does `scanf` put the null terminating character into symbol automatically, or is that something I will need to do manually?

Only if the size was enough for it to put the `nul` terminator. For example if your array was of length 10 and you input 10 chars how will it put the `nul` terminator.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of characters `scanf()` will read as so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[4];
    scanf("%3s", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./scanftest
abc
abc
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./scanftest
abcdefghijlkmnop
abc
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

`scanf()` will add the terminating `'\0'` for you.

If you don't want to hardcode the length in your format string, you can just construct it dynamically, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SYMBOL_MAX_LEN 4

int main(void) {
    char buffer[SYMBOL_MAX_LEN];
    char fstring[100];
    sprintf(fstring, "%%%ds", SYMBOL_MAX_LEN - 1);
    scanf(fstring, buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt, `scanf()` is generally a terrible function for dealing with input. `fgets()` is much better for this type of thing.

Comment: Paul, I think using `scanf` is bad idea specially when dealing with strings.

Comment: @haccks: I also think `scanf()` is an evil function, nevertheless, this answers the question, and it can be done safely.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to type '01234567890', and the program will still store the entire value?

This is because you are Unlucky that you are getting your desired result. This will invoke undefined behavior.

> Does `scanf` not prevent values from being recorded in the adjacent blocks of memory after symbol?

No.

> How could I prevent the user from entering a value of greater than length SYMBOL_MAX_LEN?

Use `fgets`.

> Does scanf put the null terminating character into symbol automatically, or is that something I will need to do manually?

Yes